# binding a command inside a listbox item to a property on the viewmodel parent

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, icommand

I've been working on this for about an hour and looked at all related SO questions.

My problem is very simple:

I have HomePageVieModel:

```
HomePageVieModel
+IList<NewsItem> AllNewsItems
+ICommand OpenNews
```

My markup:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding HomePageViewModel../>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllNewsItems}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
           <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=OpenNews}">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NewsContent}" />
           </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The list shows fine with all the items, but for the life of me whatever I try for the Command won't work:

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=OpenNewsItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=vm:HomePageViewModel, AncestorLevel=1}}">
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=OpenNewsItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=vm:HomePageViewModel,**Mode=FindAncestor}**}">
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=OpenNewsItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=vm:HomePageViewModel,**Mode=TemplatedParent}**}">
```

I just always get :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference .....

**Update**
I am setting my ViewModel like this? Didn't think this would matter:

```
 <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="HomePage" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

I use the ViewModelLocator class from the MVVMLight toolkit which does the magic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's two issue working against you here.

The `DataContext` for the `DataTemplate` is set to the item the template is displaying. This means you can't just use binding without setting a source.

The other issue is that the template means the item is not technically part of the logical tree, so you can't search for ancestors beyond the `DataTemplate` node.

To solve this you need to have the binding reach outside the logical tree. You can use a DataContextSpy defined [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ArtificialInheritanceCxt.aspx).

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllNewsItems}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <l:DataContextSpy x:Key="dataContextSpy" />
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>
                   <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataContextSpy}, Path=DataContext.OpenNews}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NewsContent}" />
                   </Hyperlink>
               </TextBlock>
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! =) Little annoying one needs a workaround for this? Isn't this kinda thing common in WPF where you want the Child item in a list bound to some parent thing!?

Comment: I'm thinking of just adding the OpenNews Command to a NewsItemViewModel and then binding the list to that, that would make setting the command easy right? I need a VM for the NewsItem anyway for some other stuff too. Or would this be a **mem/per issue**?

Comment: yes it is quite common, but do you think you can avoid the action(Command) right inside of the DataTemplate. Which might be a better User experience also.

Comment: @jobi How? This list is supposed to be like the news list you see in the start page on view studio.

Comment: In that case the Command should be part of your NewsItem Viewmodel

Comment: For Windows Phone or other light frameworks you can just put Border instead of DataContextSpy

Answer (score 30):

Slightly different example but,
I found that by referencing the parent container (using ElementName) in the binding you can get to it's DataContext and its subsequent properties using the Path syntax.  As shown below:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lstDevices" ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceMappings}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Grid>
    <ComboBox Text="{Binding Device}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstDevices, Path=DataContext.AvailableDevices}" />
    ...
   </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me when the control is a **UserControl**.  Other solutions merely linked to the root view model!

Answer (score 9):

try something like this

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.YourCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
```

he can't find your command binding inside the listbox because you set a diffrent datacontext than the viewmodel for that listbox

Comment: Works beautifully and keeps it simple. Just ignore th VS warning about datacontext being na object and VS can't look inside - although there should be a way to tell the object type too and clear the warning

Answer (score 8):

So looks like you are trying to give the proper DataContext to the HyperLink so as to trigger ICommand. 
I think a simple element name binding can solve this.

```
<Window x:Name="window" DataContext="{Binding HomePageViewModel../>
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllNewsItems}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>
       <Hyperlink DataContext="{Binding DataContext ,ElementName=window}" Command="{Binding Path=OpenNews}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NewsContent}" />
       </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The AncestorType checks only for Visual-Types not for ViewModel types.

Comment: Resetting the DataContext breaks the binding on the TextBlock

Comment: Sure it will, You can do the same idea and set the dataContext of the textbox using the StackPanel as the elementname binding reference.

Comment: +1 @Cam @Jobi unfortunately the hyperlink itself doesn't bind! =( I am setting my Window DataContext from the ViewModelLocater as a static resource. Updated the question?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a little bit late, I know. But I have only recently faced the same problem. Due to architectural reasons I decided to use a static viewmodel locator instead of the dataContextSpy.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:locator="clr-namespace: MyNamespace"
             DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static locator:ViewModelLocator.MyViewModel}}" >
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllNewsItems}">        

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Source={x:Static locator:ViewModelLocator.MyViewModel}, 
                                                     Path=OpenNews}" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NewsContent}" />
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

The static viewmodel locator instantiates the view model:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class ViewModelLocator
    {
        private static MyViewModelType myViewModel = new MyViewModelType();
        public static MyViewModelType MyViewModel 
        {
            get
            {
                return myViewModel ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this workaround is another way to bind from a data template to a command that is in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Darren works well in most cases, and should be the preferred method if possible. However, it is not a working solution where the following (niche) conditions all occur:

- *DataGrid* with *DataGridTemplateColumn*
- .NET 4
- Windows XP

...and possibly in other circumstances too. In theory it should fail on all versions of Windows; but in my experience the *ElementName* approach works in a *DataGrid* on Windows 7 upwards but not XP.

In the following fictional example, we are trying to bind to an *ICommand* called *ShowThingCommand* on the *UserControl.DataContext* (which is the ViewModel):

```
<UserControl x:Name="ThisUserControl" DataContext="whatever...">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfThings}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Thing">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, Path=ShowThingCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=ThingId}"
                            Content="{Binding Path=ThingId}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Due to the *DataTemplate* not being in the same VisualTree as the main control, it's not possible to reference back up to the control by *ElementName*.

To solve this, the little known .NET 4 and above ***{x:Reference}*** can be used. Modifying the above example:

```
<UserControl x:Name="ThisUserControl" DataContext="whatever...">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfThings}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Thing">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThisUserControl}, Path=ShowThingCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=ThingId}"
                            Content="{Binding Path=ThingId}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

For reference, see the following stackoverflow posts:

[Question 19244111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244111/what-is-the-difference-between-xreference-and-elementname)

[Question 5834336](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834336/wpf-combobox-binding-problem-in-datatemplate)

...and for an explanation of why *ElementName* doesn't work in this circumstance, see [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls) which contains a pre-.NET 4 workaround.

Comment: Nice solution, although it would be nicer if we could omit the `x:Name="ThisUserControl"`. For now I'll be using this though :-).

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListBox xmlns:model="clr-namespace:My.Space;assembly=My.Assembly"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllNewsItems, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.(model:MyNewsModel.OpenNews), Mode=OneWay}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NewsContent, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This one is quite underrated. Very simple binding without any extra elements or names. Directly bound to parent's VARIABLENAME. 

`Binding="{Binding DataContext.VARIABLENAME, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"`