# Binding ElementName in menuitem's header

Tags: c#, wpf

i try to bind the TextBox's text in MenuItem's header to MenuItem's Tag property.
but it won't work correct, always get Null in Tag property.

the code is like below...

```
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="182" Height="34" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="160,113,0,0">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Button1}" Placement="Bottom">
                <MenuItem Tag="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text}" Click="MessageBox_ShowTag">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <Grid Height="25" MinWidth="153">
                            <Label Content="Label1" Width="86" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="91,0,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

When click on menuitem, call the MessageBox to show the tag in MenuItem
( MessageBox.Show( ( sender as MenuItem ).Tag?.ToString() ); )

MessageBox has show but content is always empty.

Result:
[image: Result]

how can i bind to textbox?

Comment: What problem you are trying to solve? There could be much more better solution to that instead of storing in in Tag.

Comment: Actually, i want to bind the TextBox.Text to my attached property to menu item.  And then when click menu item, i can get the value by sender in Click_Event.  i also has other menuitem that has no TextBox in it, but also have attached property( just write in xaml ), so i can get the value by user click on any menuitem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have to bind it like that. An alternative would be to bind to a property (here: `MyText`) that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and then pass the `DataContext` to the menu like this:

```
 <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Placement="Bottom"  DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <Grid Height="25" MinWidth="153">
                                <Label Content="Label1" Width="86" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Path=MyText}"
                                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="91,0,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
```

And then not relay on `Click` event to get the `TextBox` value at all.

If you want to know why your binding doesn't work, its because your `MenuItem` can't find an object named `TextBox1` in its `Namescope`. If you must (namescopes are a bit tricky), you may make it work by creating a new [Namescope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.100).aspx) for your `MenuItem` and registering the name for the `TextBox`:

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(mi1, new NameScope());
mi1.RegisterName("TextBox1", TextBox1);
```

where `mi1` is the name of your `MenuItem`, then your binding will work:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Placement="Bottom">
            <MenuItem Tag="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text}" Click="MessageBox_ShowTag" Name="mi1">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <Grid Height="25" MinWidth="153">
                        <Label Content="Label1" Width="86" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Name="TextBox1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="91,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Also, avoid `x:Name` whenever you can. [It can cause some nasty memory leaks](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/). Use Name instead.

Comment: i can't get the TextBox1 in code. so i can't use "mi1.RegisterName("TextBox1", TextBox1);" this to regist TextBox.
But thanks for your other information, learn a lot of it.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comment also, there could be better solution to actual problem you are trying to solve.

But anyhow if you want solution for your specific problem it can be solved by using `x:Reference` in place of `ElementName` like this:

```
<MenuItem Tag="{Binding Source={x:Reference TextBox1}, Path=Text}"/>
```

ElementName is not working because VisualTree is different. In case interested read further here - [ElementName v/s x:Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244111/what-is-the-difference-between-xreference-and-elementname).

Comment: @PGCafe - That will be just error in designer. Have you tried running your code and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding via `RelativeSource`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="91,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: He wants to bind Tag property of MenuItem to Text property of TextBox. You offer an opposite solution.

Comment: Uh, you are right. I'll cover my head with ashes. But it still works; thanks to `DependencyProperty`s and `TwoWay` data binding mode.