# x:Reference vs Storyboard.TargetName

Tags: wpf, xaml

In WPF, is there any real reason to use `Storyboard.TargetName="myElement"` instead of `Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference myElement}"`?

Comment: What did you find when you read the documentation on both of them?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based off [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19244917/3113406) and [**this MS forum** (has examples with pictures)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7813ba61-f7d3-49c3-a1f4-2fe8337ca407/difference-between-xreference-and-elementname?forum=wpf)

---

MS does not comment on this, although from researching I have concluded that **ElementName** is the way to go as:

1. ElementName is optimised for UiElements and won't work for Non-UIElements
2. x:Reference returns a reference to the object. ElementName looks for the object in the VisualTree so it is already in memory.
3. x:Reference searches a scope (usually top-level window) to search for the element (e.g. Window.UserNameTB) which most likely gives a performance overhead when compared to navigating the VisualTree (cannot say for sure as I did not program that functionality).

- `{x:Reference ...} ->`

  - returns just a reference of an object it doesn't create that "bridge" between two properties like binding would do.
  - Behind all that a service is being used that searches for the given name in a specific scope which is usually the window itself.

- `{Binding ElementName="..." } ->`

  - Creates that binding object then it searches for the object name. The search algorithm moves up and/or down in VisualTree to find the desired element.
  - Therefore a functional VisualTree is always needed. As example when used inside a Non-UiElement, it won't work. In the end the Binding stays and does its daily bread.