# x:Reference "" is not a valid value for the property "IsVisible"

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019

I am relatively new to WPF and really like the possibility to do to GUI logic in the markup. 
Currently, I have a control which I only want to be visible, if another control is visible.

```
<AttachedControl IsVisible="{x:Reference Name=mainControl}"/>
<MasterControl Name="mainControl" IsVisible="True">
...
</MasterControl>
```

When I am using this, it is working in the designer, but produces the error message:

> Error     "" is no valid value for the property
>   "IsVisible".  ProjectX    MyUserControl.xaml

It also compiles successfully and I can run the app. So can anybody tell me where is the problem or what I am doing/understanding wrong?

Comment: You probably want to use data binding: `IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, ElementName=mainControl}"`.

Comment: Even though I am not yet understanding, it is working. :)

Comment: It's not a good idea to start coding WPF/XAML without understanding the basic concepts. Probably read some introductory material. E.g. *WPF Unleashed* by Adam Nathan, a really good book.

Comment: That's what this project is about. Starting with WPF. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x:Reference` markup extension refers to an element's `x:Name` but you cannot bind the `IsVisible` property to the control with the `x:Name` "mainControl" itself. You should bind to a boolean property of it.

This should work provided that `mainControl` has an `IsVisible` property, i.e. the `x:Reference` is the *source* of the binding and `IsVisible` is the path:

```
<AttachedControl IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Source={x:Reference Name=mainControl}}"/>
```

You can also bind to another element by setting the `ElementName` property of the binding:

```
<AttachedControl IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, ElementName=mainControl}"/>
```

[What is the difference between x:Reference and ElementName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244111/what-is-the-difference-between-xreference-and-elementname)