# why custom control binding cause an error?

Tags: wpf

The code is as follows

1.MainWindow.cs

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="HelloButton" Width="100">Hello</Button>
        <lib:TestControl Width="100" TestValue="{Binding ElementName=HelloButton,Path=Width}">
            <lib:TestControl.Some>
                <lib:SomePropertyClass Inner="{Binding ElementName=HelloButton,Path=Width}"/>
            </lib:TestControl.Some>
        </lib:TestControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

2.TestControl.cs

```
public class TestControl : Control
{
    static TestControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TestControl)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TestValue", typeof(int), typeof(TestControl));
    public int TestValue
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(TestValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(TestValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Some", typeof(SomePropertyClass), typeof(TestControl));
    public SomePropertyClass Some
    {
        get => (SomePropertyClass)GetValue(SomeProperty);
        set => SetValue(SomeProperty, value);
    }
}

public class SomePropertyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Inner", typeof(int), typeof(SomePropertyClass));
    public int Inner
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(InnerProperty);
        set => SetValue(InnerProperty, value);
    }
}
```

3.TestControl.xaml

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Content="{TemplateBinding TestValue}"/>
                        <Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=Some.Inner}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

'TestValue' property binding is expected,but why the 'Inner' property Binding cause an error?

'System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Width; DataItem=null; target element is 'SomePropertyClass' (HashCode=63183526); target property is 'Inner' (type 'Int32')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the 'Inner' property Binding cause an error?

Because the element `HelloButton` cannot be found by the search algorithm. `x:Reference` should work:

```
<lib:SomePropertyClass Inner="{Binding Path=Width,Source={x:Reference HelloButton}}"/>
```

`SomePropertyClass` is not in the same [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) as `HelloButton` but `TestControl` is.

[What is the difference between x:Reference and ElementName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244111/what-is-the-difference-between-xreference-and-elementname)

Comment: `x:Reference`  could not use on parents?

Comment: Parents? No, it references an element. Did you see the link I posted?

Comment: yeah，i mean it will cause circular reference issue.

Comment: It won't in your example at least.