# WPF DataGrid - Binding Source and Width to different objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

In my WPF application, I have a DataGrid which is bound to a collection in the viewmodel, but I want the width of the first column to be equal to a property on the viewmodel itself, like so:

```
public ObservableCollection<Booking> Bookings
{
    return repository.Bookings();
}

public int MaxWidth
{
    return 100;
}
```

(I realise there's no point in binding to a fixed property like this - it's for demo purposes)

```
<UserControl>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Bookings}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.MaxWidth}" Header="Provider" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

But if I do this, the width of the column remains at the default value - i.e. just wide enough to accommodate its value.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Attempted this, to see what happened:

```
<Label Name="tricky" Content="500" Visibility="Collapsed"></Label>
...
<DataGridTextColumn Width="{Binding ElementName=tricky, Path=Content}" Header="Provider" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
```

Which did nothing. Is it not possible to set the width dynamically?

Comment: Shouldn't your RelativeSource binding be finding a `DataGrid` instead of a `UserControl`?

Comment: I don't think so - the property I'm looking for belongs to the overall parent ViewModel, not the DataGrid. A quick test confirms it makes no difference.

Comment: @MattThrower that's correct. You want the DataContext scope of the UserControl, not the Booking object. When does the DataGrid Binding happen?

Comment: Hmm. This is MVVM based so I'm not controlling the timing of the bindings. Bookings is populated before MaxWidth, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Have you seen this? You may need to try using Reference instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313586/binding-datagrid-column-width

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I was reading that wrong. Does it work if you give your UserControl a name and use an ElementName binding instead? It's possible it's picking up a different UserControl in the hierarchy than the one you expect. Also, does binding MaxWidth instead of Width work?

Comment: @d.moncada Sorry to be dense, but I can't see how to get that syntax to work. Every time I try it, I get "object reference not set" errors.

Comment: @Rachel No, that compiles, but is never called.

Comment: @d.moncada Seems like x:Reference is not properly supported in WPF? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644924/when-is-xreference-in-wpf-resolved-and-why-does-xaml-element-order-affect-it

Comment: I think the problem is the `DataGridTextColum` is not part of the Visual Tree (can verify with [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)), so the binding never gets resolved. The data obtained from the `DataGridTextColumn` is used to build the DataGridCell template, and at the time the template is built, the DataContext isn't set. My suggestion would be to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, and specify your own CellTemplate that has the Width binding you need.

Comment: @Rachel You are correct, thank you! If you'd like to re-post that as the answer, I can amend with an example and I'll accept it. Nice blog, BTW - been invaluable in helping me get to grips with WPF.

Comment: @MattThrower Its posted below, and thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the `DataGridTextColum` is not part of the Visual Tree (can verify with [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)), so the binding never gets resolved.

The data obtained from the `DataGridTextColumn` is used to build the DataGridCell template, and at the time the template is built, the `DataContext` isn't set.

My suggestion would be to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, and specify your own `CellTemplate` that has the `Width` binding you need.

Answer (score 0):

`MaxWidth` and `Bookings` are siblings aren't they? So binding expressions for them should be identical.

Looking at your first XAML: `Path=DataContext.MaxWidth` - remove `DataContext`.
Looking at the second XAML: no need to specify `Path` twice, the first `Path` is enough, I'm not even sure if the actual construct is valid.

Generally, a lot of low level UI properties are POCOs rather than DPs, just make sure your target one is a DP.

**Update** - what you might want to do is to use `FallbackValue = 900` as part of your binding expression, just to narrow the problem down - whether it's a binding problem or the target property isn't suitable for using as binding target.

**Update 2** - most times you'll find yourself running out of steam rather quickly when going for that low level of managing your UI, it's often beneficial to create MVColum, managing headers, widths etc and create a behavior, which can apply all these settings in one go. Also that way you won't be dependent on a flavor of your target properties as you'll be setting them up right in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively a useful feature I use is as follow

```
IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"  />
```

This allows you to link to properties outside of the itemssource of your grid.