# WPF ListView with buttons on each line

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, datatemplate

I have a list of `Games` which just has an `ID`, a `Date`, and a `Time`.
I am setting this list as the `DataContext`.

I then have a `DataTemplate` for these games that is:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Game}">
     <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock Name="dateBlock" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                    Text="{Binding Date,  StringFormat=d}"></TextBlock>
         <TextBlock Name="TimeBlock" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                    Text="{Binding Time}"></TextBlock>
         //need to but a button here for each row
     </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

To use the template, I am simply just doing this:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ListBox>
```

I need to add a `Button` to each line in this list view that have the same click event, but will somehow pass the ID of the game for which button is being clicked.

How can I do this?  I am stuck.
If it doesn't make sense let me know and I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For the first part, add a `Button` to the `DataTemplate` and subscribe to the `Click` event

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Game}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="dateBlock" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Date,  StringFormat=d}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="TimeBlock" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Time}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">X</Button>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In the code behind event handler, you can get the `DataContext` of the clicked `Button` and find out the Id like

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    Game game = button.DataContext as Game;
    int id = game.ID;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: did you mean Grid.Row="0"?

Answer (score 17):

Easily. Add a `Button` to your *DataTemplate*, give it a `Command` and then set the `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`. The *DataContext* within a DataTemplate is the object.

As requested, some links to using commands.

- [WPF Commands Part 1: Basics](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/wpf-commands-part-1-basics/)
- [WPF Commands Part 2: Command Bindings and Gestures](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/wpf-commands-part-2-command-bindings-and-gestures/)
- [MSDN Understanding Routed Events and Commands In WPF (ADVANCED)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx)

HTH,

Comment: It is a neater solution. Since I've been writing MVVM code I do even think to use event handlers in code behind (i.e. *xaml.cs*). It is just so much nicer.

Comment: Dennis, a code example of how to do the rest of the Command Binding (or at least a link to an existing one) would be really helpful in your answer.

In these cases, I also prefer using Commands with the parameter using Binding.

Comment: @Ether: I would usually throw together an example when it is required, however as Commands are such well covered topic I will do the Google search and add a few of the better results to my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, this may be neater but I was getting confused with the commands. I may change it later, but for now the other answer was easier for me :) thanks!

Comment: It's better explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063308/binding-a-command-inside-a-listbox-item-to-a-property-on-the-viewmodel-parent

Answer (score 4):

With a ListBox.ItemTemplate.   Then in your click event you can get the object via DataContext.

```
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="^" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsNotFirst, Mode=OneWay}" 
             Click="btnMoveFDAup"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


    private void btnMoveFDAup(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = ((Button)sender);
        // btn.DataContext will get you to the row object where you can retrieve the ID
    }
```

Comment: How would I get the values from btn.DataContext? For example, in the debugger I can see that btn.DataContext is pointing to my class of data (LVDATA) and what I need is the value in string Name. How do I access this?