# ListView with Buttons and Label as Items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a list in which I want to display Items and let the user modify them when viewing it directly. There should be a label and a few buttons next to it on every "list item". Is there any way I can do that? I was using python with PyQt5 before and got it working, kind of, now im stuck with C#.

I'm not looking for code, just a direction I would need to go, I wanna figure it out myself.

Comment: PyQt5  Is a python packager, why is labeled as c#?

Comment: @styx I think it's just something he was able to do in PyQt5, and we would like to do the same in C# I guess... dustin-we, what are you using? WPF or winforms? If WPF are you trying to apply MVVM pattern?

Comment: @Mikitori yes, you are right. I was using python with PyQt5 before, I'm pretty new to C#, so i need some help. I am using winforms, I'll write that into the description for more clarity.

Comment: I read that WPF is the "newer" technology, would it be better to use it over Windows Forms? Since I'm starting to learn C#, I can still swap.

Comment: I cannot agree more ^^. WPF needs some adaptation, but the responsive aspect by default is nice, and xaml is pretty straight forward to learn + you can find lots of examples + then you can apply MVVM pattern ;)

Comment: In Winforms I would use either a TableLayoutPanel or a FlowLayoutPanel, mayb hosting UserControls that hold the Controls you want, instead of a ListView. If you can, WPF is certainly the more powerful target, albeit somewhat harder to get started..

Comment: for the wpf part, once started (if you chose to do so) SO contains lots of answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127920/wpf-listview-with-buttons-on-each-line